# How do you mark a directory "in use" so it cannot be deleted or renamed?

Tags: c#, .net, filesystems

I am writing a class that will encapsulate a temporary folder. The folder will hold files as the program works with them and then delete itself when the object is disposed.

I would like to prevent the temporary folder from being messed with while in use. I know it is possible to keep a folder "locked" without altering any of the permissions-- for example, if you open a command prompt and set the working directory to a particular folder, you won't be able to delete that folder unless you close the command prompt or change the working directory to something else. Is there a way to do that in c#, programmatically?

I know it is possible with this:

```
var path = @"c:\temp\MyFolderName";
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
System.Environment.CurrentDirectory = path;
System.IO.Directory.Delete(path); //Throws error
```

...but this limits me to one working folder (and seems sort of kludgy).

I know we can lock a file just by opening it, but there does not appear to be a way to "open" a directory.

Comment: Create temp file there and lock it?

Answer (score 3):

The most straightforward way is just create temp file in that directory and lock it (open with `FileShare.None`):

```
var directory = @"G:\tmp\so\locked";
var fileHandle = new FileStream(
    Path.Combine(directory, ".lock"), 
    FileMode.Create, 
    FileAccess.ReadWrite, 
    FileShare.None);            
try {
    // now, you cannot delete or rename that folder until you press a key
    Console.ReadKey();
}
finally {
    fileHandle.Dispose();
}
```

If that for whatever reason does not satisfy you - you can obtain handle to directory itself. I'm not aware of a way to do that with pure .NET, but you can do that with native winapi (`CreateFile`, but despite its name, it doesn't create file or directory, just obtains handle):

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true, BestFitMapping = false)]
private static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(string lpFileName, FileAccess dwDesiredAccess, FileShare dwShareMode, IntPtr securityAttrs, FileMode dwCreationDisposition, int dwFlagsAndAttributes, IntPtr hTemplateFile);

var directory = @"G:\tmp\so\locked";
var directoryHandle = CreateFile(
    directory, 
    FileAccess.ReadWrite, 
    FileShare.Read, 
    IntPtr.Zero, 
    FileMode.Open, 
    0x02000000, // << this flag is needed to obtain handle to directory
    IntPtr.Zero);
if (directoryHandle.IsInvalid)
    throw new Exception("Failed to obtain handle to directory");
try {
    Console.ReadKey();
}
finally {
    directoryHandle.Dispose();
}
```

It will have the same effect (directory cannot be deleted or renamed until you release the handle), but without additional files.

Answer (score -3):

There is a `DirectorySecurity` class in [`System.Security.AccessControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.directorysecurity(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Example taken straight from the documentation :

```
AddDirectorySecurity(DirectoryName, @"MYDOMAIN\MyAccount", FileSystemRights.ReadData, AccessControlType.Allow);

public static void AddDirectorySecurity(string FileName, string Account, FileSystemRights Rights, AccessControlType ControlType)
{
      // Create a new DirectoryInfo object.
      DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(FileName);

      // Get a DirectorySecurity object that represents the 
      // current security settings.
      DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();

      // Add the FileSystemAccessRule to the security settings. 
      dSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(Account, Rights, ControlType));

      // Set the new access settings.
      dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);
}
```

Comment: Please take note of "without altering any of the permissions" from the question.